# htaccess add condition replace string from parameter in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried to clean the strings from requests with the help of a function

file.php

```
<?php
echo 'test';
if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET))
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value))
            $_GET[$key] = sanit($value);
    }
sanit($item) {
    if(is_array($item))  {
        foreach($item as $key => $val)  {
            $inputstring[$key] = sanitizare($val);
        }
    } else {
        $item= filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $item= filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
        $item= preg_replace('/(0x)(\d{2,})/i', 'OOO', $item);
        $item= preg_replace('/(0o)(\d{2,})/i', 'OOO', $item);
        $item= preg_replace('/(0b)(\d{2,})/i', 'OOO', $item);
    }
    return   $item;
}
```

I import this file.php with htaccess, but it does not identify the requests, but echo works:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "...file.php"
```

Because I didn't succeed with this method, I'm thinking if I can rewrite all requests in htaccess.
I have this link: http://domain/test/test1.php?ref=0x12546.

How can I change from 0x12546 to 000

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not identify the requests"? What exactly are you expecting that code to do? There's nothing particularly wrong with the code you posted, although you are sanitizing based purely on the value, not the key, and the code you posted is obviously part "pseudo-code" - so we can only assume what your `sanit()` function is doing. If this is for SEO then you will obviously need to issue a redirect. (_Aside:_ No need to check `isset()` when you are checking `!empty()`.) In your example URL, is the URL-path static? Could there be other URL params that need to be preserved?

Comment: I modified the post and added the content of the function. I'm not interested in SEO, I was recently hacked by sqlmap.py and I want to secure all my GET, POST, etc. requests